# How match 'other' applications to a tag in awesome-wm?

Tags: window-manager, awesome-wm, lua

I use version 3.3.4 of awesome and it is fine. But I miss one thing I could do with an older version of awesome (without configuration via Lua): I could add a matcher with the regular expression .* to add all windows without another tag to a specific tag:

```
rule { name = ".*" tags = "9" }
```

With that all applications I didn't made another rule for were added to tag 9. How can I do something similar with configuration in rc.lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found following solution, that works so far:

```
awful.rules.rules = {

-- All clients will match this rule.
{ rule = { },
  properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
                 border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                 focus = true,
                 keys = clientkeys,
                 buttons = clientbuttons,
                 tag = tags[1][9]         } },
```

This is placed before the other rules, matching specific applications.