# Set window to use current tag with Awesome WM

Tags: awesome-wm

I followed the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/123542/how-match-other-applications-to-a-tag-in-awesome-wm) to move "other" windows to a particular tag. How do I escape a window from picking up this rule, ie, how do I get the window to show on the current tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spent some "quality" time figuring this out for Firefox dialogs yesterday. My main browser windows all go to [1][1]. But when I hook up an external monitor, send some browser windows to [2][1], various Firefox dialogs still pop up on [1][1]. This is a problem when monitor 1 has another tag active - then you don't even know there's a dialog waiting for input on [1][1] until you remember why the browser on [2][1] doesn't respond to anything.

My solution:

```
{ rule = { class = "Firefox" }, properties = { tag = tags[1][1] } },
{ rule = { class = "Firefox", instance = "Dialog" }, callback = function(c) awful.client.movetotag(tags[mouse.screen][awful.tag.getidx()], c) end},
```

awful.tag.getidx() returns the current tag.